# Is there a way to remove a tooltip of a plugin via custom CSS?

Tags: plugins, css, tooltip

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this. I have gotten away with manipulating a lot of the values on the front-end of Wordpress pages using custom CSS on various themes, but I've hit a wall this time and I'm not sure how to over come.

In this instance, one of the plugins has a tooltip in an input box that I'd like to remove.

[image]

Upon inspection, I couldn't find where the tooltip element but I did find something here:

```
<td class="active">
     <input data-manage-stock="" 
          data-purchasable="1" 
          data-instock="1" 
          data-backorders="0" 
          data-max="" 
          data-price="4.5" 
          data-vmsg="Currently unavailable" 
          title="$4.50" ////////////////This value I need removed!!!
          id="qty_input_0" 
          data-column="1" 
          class="number qty_input" 
          type="text" 
          name="order_info[0][quantity]">
</td>
```

Link to test product: https://www.customwear.com/shop/atc1015/

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It’d only be possible to remove without JavaScript if the plugin had a filter you could use, but you’d need to refer to the plugin’s support for help with that.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS - unfortunately no :(

The best way of course if you remove it just from HTML. Try to search for all files and look if there is a function like `apply_filters()` - it allows you to remove that attribute via `preg_replace()` or with even simpler way.

If you can not find the way to remove it in HTML, you can do it with jQuery/JavaScript (obviously need to make sure jquery is enqueued).

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.number.qty_input').removeAttr('title');
});
```

Comment: That's what I said. What is the reason to copy my own answer to my comments?

Comment: lol sorry...... but reading it again, you are still assuming it is an html generated, not injected with JS